# Repulsive domain walls in gravity - current status of the field?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, gravitational-waves, cosmological-inflation

I know that in gravity domain-wall solutions are known to be repulsive. See e.g. [this paper](https://inspirehep.net/record/193691). Does anybody know anything about the current state of this field? It seems natural and appealing to try to use this phenomenon as, say, a possible explanation for anomalous speeds of some galaxies? (in order to avoid introducing 'dark matter')

Comment: Don't know status. I understand that some people have thought that possibly some or all apparent cosmic voids might be from domain walls, but no gravitational waves have been detected that people have thought would come from cosmic string or early universe domain walls. eLISA I also think should be able to detect those gravitational waves if they exist, above a certain level. If I understand it LIGO is too small for them. But, really, I am remembering random facts I've read on, and don't know the real status.... Would love to read an answer